# External hard drive set with No Jumper = DS (slave)

Tags: hard-drive, jumper

My external hard drive has the following label:

> No Jumper = DS (slave)

What does it mean? Does it mean that I will not need to adjust the jumper anymore?

Comment: My guess would be yes, if that is what it says. Can you also write the model number and I will just try to double check for you.

Answer (score 5):

Western Digital has a good white sheet explaining hard disk jumper settings [here](http://www.wdc.com/en/library/eide/2579-001037.pdf).  Basically, "No Jumper = DS (slave)" means that the drive will act as a slave (secondary) drive in a 2-drive system.

Comment: +1 ...With "DS" standing for "Drive Select", as opposed to "CS" standing for "Cable Select".  Basically, the jumpers on the drive for Master vs Slave take precedence over their order of connection on the cable.  Cable Select used to be very common, now Drive Select is prevalent (and easier.)